# AutoRest - How to parameterise the hostname

Tags: autorest

I have what feels like a fairly basic requirement when using the AutoRest utility.

My OpenAPI spec has a "servers" property with the like so:

```
 "servers": [
{
  "url": "https://{{tenant}}.api.{{domain}}.com"
}],
```

The classes generated result in static hostname references as follows:

```
// generate request object
            var _url = new global::System.Uri($"https://{{tenant}}.api.{{domain}}.com{pathAndQuery}");
```

I want to use the generated lib across many environments/tenants and don't want to generate a specific set of libs per tenant.

Before I go too far down a rabbit hole, I figured I would ask here how best to achieve a parameterised hostname rather than hardcoded into the generated functions. What I would settle for is a param 'url' by default on each API call generated. I figure nearly everyone must do this with autorest so I am sure I am just missing something simple.

Any help appreciated.